# Moment of inertia for a triatomic molecule

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

What does the moment of inertia for a molecule mean? How is it useful? Most importantly, how would I go about solving it for a triatomic molecule?

Comment: blank shot: did you read wikipedia article on the subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) is defined for a molecule as it would be for any other solid: you consider the nuclei as points with mass, ignore the mass of the electrons, and you can then calculate either the scalar moment of inertia or the [tensor of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Moment_of_inertia_tensor).

The moment of inertia of a molecule is involved in the quantification of its rotational movements. Of the top of my head, the two areas of chemistry where this plays a big role are:

- [rotational spectroscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_spectroscopy): the rotation of a molecule is quantized, and the value that the angular momentum can take are related to the moment of inertia of the molecule.
- the rotational entropy of a molecule is linked through statistical mechanics to its inertia tensor.